# Cannot reach a dynamic page with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I need to read data on https://www.cmegroup.com/tools-information/quikstrike/options-calendar.html
I tried to click on FX tab from page.click in puppeteer, but the page remains on the default.
Any help welcome

Comment: share your code please

Comment: following : in bigger font is the selector of the button I want to click.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    let scrape = async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.cmegroup.com/tools-information/quikstrike/options-calendar.html');

    await page.waitFor(1000);
```

//div select FX
        await page.click('#ctl00_MainContent_ucViewControl_IntegratedCMEOptionExpirationCalendar_ucViewControl_ucProductSelector_lvGroups_ctrl3_lbProductGroup');

```
    //browser.close();
    return result;
    };

    scrape().then((value) => {
    console.log(value); // Success!
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the element you're looking for on that page. However, this might be helpful:

Wait for the selector to appear on the page before clicking on it:

```js
await page.waitForSelector(selector);
```

If still facing the issue, try using Javascript click method:

```js
await page.$eval(selector, elem => elem.click());
```